# How to detect contact between 2 SKSpriteNodes. Swift, Sprite kit

Tags: swift

I created this game in xcode using Sprite Kit and Swift and I am trying to figure out how I can detect when the hero makes contact with a wall. So far this is my code. However I can't seem to find collision when I do SKPhysicsBody.

class GameScene: SKScene {

```
var movingGround: TFMovingGround!
var hero: TFHero!
var isStarted = false
var wallGenerator: TFWallGenerator!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green:201.00/255.0, blue:244.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)

    movingGround = TFMovingGround(size:CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, kMLGroundHeight))
    movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2)
    addChild(movingGround)

    hero = TFHero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70,movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)

    addChild(hero)
    hero.breath()

    //Add WallGenerator
    wallGenerator = TFWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    wallGenerator.position = view.center
    addChild(wallGenerator)


}
```

}

This is my code in the GameScene.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A difficult way to go about it would be to get the frame of HeroSprite and get the frame for WallsSprite and see if they overlap, using

CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2)

and doing this continuously.

A better solution would be to use collision detection. There is a pretty good [tutorial here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Swift_iOS_8_Sprite_Kit_Collision_Handling_Tutorial).